# Is there a method for determining whether a number has an n'th integer root? Does 249344 have such a root? What is it?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

I've tried a few possible roots. But now my head hurts. Please help.

Comment: If you mean square root, by arithmetic we can find an integer $n$ such that $n^2\lt 249244\lt (n+1)^2$, so the answer is no. One could also note that $249344\equiv 2\pmod{3}$. Since any square is cngruent to $0$ or $1$ modulo $3$, our number is not a perfect square.

Comment: $249344$ is slightly below $500^2=250000$, but too slightly to be $\le499^2=500^2-2\cdot500+1$, so, no, $249344$ is not a perfect square.

Comment: Do you mean an integer square root?  An integer n-th root for any integer $n$?

Comment: @rgettman I meant an nth root.

Answer (score 10):

Start by finding the prime factorization. Here, it is $249344= 2^9\cdot 487^1$.
If $249344$ were an $n$th power, all exponents would be multiples of $n$. But $\gcd(9,1)=1$, so no luck with this number.

Of course, a very partial factorization suffices or at leat allows you to reduce the trial search: If you are not sure if $487$ is prime or not, even knowing that $2^9||249344$ suffices that at most $\sqrt[3]\cdot$ or $\sqrt[9]\cdot$ can be integer (and since $3|9$, the latter will automatically fail if the former fails).
So, factoring out all $2,3,5$ will typically boil the possible roots down a lot.

But what if no small prime factors can be found? Say you have a ten digit number and it is not divisible by any prime $\in\{2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19\}$? Then at leat you can stop trying roots as soon as the (noninteger) result gets smaller than the next prine, $23$, which happens after $\sqrt[8]\cdot$ at this size, i.e. here you need only check $\sqrt\cdot,\sqrt[3]\cdot,\sqrt[5]\cdot,\sqrt[7]\cdot$.

Comment: Thanks! I'll accept this answer after I create an account and sign in.

Comment: This method is quite effective here (+1), but in general determining whether a number is a perfect power is much faster than factoring the number - a simple bisection algorithm allows for perfect power testing in time polynomial in the length of the number, whereas factoring of course isn't known to be.